# Does Visual Studio support directing build output to multiple directories?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, project-properties

Every time I do a build using Visual Studio 2008, I have to manually copy the output files to two additional directories on my computer.  Is there a way to configure my projects, so that when the output files are generated copies of them are automatically placed in the additional directories?

Comment: Just in case you fail/can't configure VS to do that,you can make a batch script that will automaticly copy that.Here:http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/55203-batch-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: This is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4331387/1608072

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure post-build step in your projects.

Comment: How do I do that?  If I already knew, I would have needed to ask if it was possible.

Comment: Open project properties, go to Build Events page and write any commands (e.g. specify a batch file)