# multiple exe in bin folder after build solution

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to produce more than one exe in debug/release folder after we build Windows form solution?

For example I want to produce 2 exes in debug/release folder everytime I build a solution, 1. MyApp.exe 2. MyApp_setup.exe

Thanks

Comment: Suppose you are using Visual Studio, you can make use of [Post Build Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324347/vs-2010-post-build-copy-files-in-to-multiple-directories-multiple-output-path).

Comment: Create 2 projects within 1 solution. Compile the solution as opposed to compiling the project. Is this the sort of thing that you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: The problem if i add a project is, each project will have its own folder in the solution folder, which each will have its own debug/release folder.. While what i try to achive is two exes in one debug/release folder, so the twi exes will share the same default settings

Comment: The HOWEVER part in the below answer was useful when I had service, winform utilites, and monitor utilties, that differed only by the exe.  They shared the same 21 other assemblies in the solution.  A single solution was prefered for the build pipeline I was using.

Answer (score 6):

The `\bin\Debug` and `\bin\Release` folders are only defaults and can be changed in your project settings.

[image]
<sup>(Click for larger view)</sup>

All you need to do is change it to a relative path to be something both projects can see.

For example, if your folder structure was like

```
C:\
 Code\
  MyAppSolution\
   MyApp\
   MyApp_Setup\
```

changing both projects to use `..\CommonBin\Debug\` as their output path would put both exe's in `C:\Code\MyAppSolution\CommonBin\Debug\`.

---

However there is a second option also, if you add a reference to the `MyApp` project to `MyApp_Setup` when you go to build `MyApp_Setup` it will put `MyApp.exe` in the output directory because it considered it a dependency. Just be sure you have `Copy Local` set to `true` when you build.

[image]

Comment: The HOWEVER part above is perfect... Multiple .NET EXE Projects in the same solution build to the same single output directory.   A useful single sln solution file scenario.